# reindex elasticsearch api timeout with large size of document

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am re-indexing one index from python but size of document is large (6gig) and it take 60 min, so I am getting **time out** in api.

**Code:**

```
def Reindex(src, dest):
    query = {

        "source": {
            "index": src,
            "query": {
                "range": {
                    "UTC_date": {
                        "lt": "now-15d/d"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "dest": {
            "index": dest
        }
    }
    Query = {
        "query": {
            "range": {
                "UTC_date": {
                    "lt": "now-15d/d"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    try:
        result = es.reindex(query, wait_for_completion=True, request_timeout=300)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: you mean the size of the index is large and not the document right?

Comment: size of index is large and take 60 min to compelete,i get time out in api after some minutes but task of reindex complete. i want get response of finishing reindex

Comment: A timeout simply means that the request is still running but the HTTP connection from to ES has timed out. You will not be able to the get the finished response because of the time taken.

You can still see the request going on by using the task management API:

`GET _tasks?actions=*reindex&detailed`

Comment: how use this api in python GET _tasks?actions=*reindex&detailed in pyrhon   Sharath

Answer (score 0):

i found solution.because i reindex 6gig it takse more time so i increased time out and now it work

```
def Reindex(src, dest):
    print("[X] START Reindex")
    query = {

        "source": {
            "index": src,
            "query": {
                "range": {
                    "UTC_date": {
                        "lt": "now-1d/d"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "dest": {
            "index": dest
        }
    }
    Query = {
        "query": {
            "range": {
                "UTC_date": {
                    "lt": "now-1d/d"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    try:
        result = es.reindex(query, wait_for_completion=True, request_timeout=10000,conflicts="proceed")
        print(result)
        log_dict = {}
        log_dict['total']=result['total']
        log_dict['created']=result['created']
        log_dict['updated']=result['updated']
        log_dict["Timestamp"] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        if log_dict['total']==(log_dict['created']+log_dict['updated']):
            print("gggggg")
            log_dict['status'] = 'success'
            Delete(src)
        else:
            log_dict['status'] = 'failure'
        access_logger.info(json.dumps(log_dict))
```